# What statistical test should be used to compare groups when the assumption of independence is violated?

Tags: chi-squared-test, independence, fishers-exact-test, kruskal-wallis-test, observational-study

I would like to test if there are statistically significant differences between three groups (defined by an outcome measurement) for some categorical and continous variables, respectively. Normality cannot be assumed. The sample-size is small (n~60).

Observations are hospital admittance for a specific acute disease entity.

Some (few) patients are afflicted by this acute disease several times making the assumption of independence invalid. One patient can occur several times and in different outcome groups. Kruskal-wallis and Fisher's exact test can therefore not be used, if I'm not misstaken.

For continous variables the Datta-Satten test (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4742085_Rank-Sum_Tests_for_Clustered_Data) seems appropriate and produces reasonable results. But how do I test the categorical variables for differences in proportions between the three groups? Is there a Fisher's exact test for clustered data?

Help would be appreciated

Comment: This sounds like it could be a mixed effects logistic regression.

Comment: Is that appropriate in the setting of a small sample size and (most likely) non-linerarity, heteroskedacicity and/or non-normality of residuals in log-odds-scale? I was (probably errorenous) thinking that something 'related' to fisher's exact test or the chi-square test would rely less on assumptions of the underlying distribution.